# Android - LinearLayout/RelativeLayout Alignment

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am attempting to create a simple UI that looks something like this[image]

I am very new to android and have been trying different types of layouts (Linear/Relative) and I believe Linear may be the way to go here (I hope to make the amount of ListViews dynamic at some stage but for now 2 is fine).

Should I be using a Linear Layout or Relative layout, or some combination of both to achieve this.

Here is the XML which I have, I can't seem to get the button to align right, even though its gravity is set to right. I am open to any suggestions on how to fix this, or if there is a better way

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.9"

    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

edit : here is what the UI currently looks like[image]

Comment: Take Relative Layout as a main. Then take linear layout in which you put both listviews. Then add button on main relative layout and set align parent right true and below the linear layout.

Comment: How can layout nesting be avoided in this instance, what if I wanted to make listView1 30% of width and listView2 50% of the width, considering I am now using @sanatshukla 's answer I dont really see how we can do this without layout nesting.

Comment: I posted an answer to show you how to take full advantage of RelativeLayout to avoid layout nesting. But mine uses 50% and 50% for the ListViews. There's no evidence in your question that you wanted a 30% and 50%. Not even in your drawing.

Comment: You are correct, there is no evidence in the question, but I was just wondering how I can extend all of the answers given as well

Comment: Pls check my answer too, If it does not work for you i'll delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnButton"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ListView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </ListView>
        <ListView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Note that setting the height of ListView 's to wrap_content is not recommended and I guess they should be match_parent in this case. Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&t=40m50s

Comment: @suphug22 if this answer is helpful then accept it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

OK, you can do one thing.

```
<RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout> <!-- horizontal orientation with weightsum 2 -->

<LinearLayout>  <!-- vertical orientation with layout weight 1 and width 0dp --> 
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout>  <!-- vertical orientation with layout weight 1 and width 0dp -->
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>  

<Button /> <!-- alignParentBottom = true and alignParentLeft = true --> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the LinearLayout around the Button or set its orientation to vertical.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this also achieves the desired result

Answer (score 2):

Avoid **layout nesting**.
A **single** RelativeLayout is enough.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <!-- Set the Button, first: Bottom and right aligned -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="New Button"
    />

    <!-- Trick: set a dummy View in the middle of the screen -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/dummy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />

    <!-- Now the ListViews: -->
    <!-- One above the button and to the left of the dummy -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/button"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/dummy"
    />

    <!-- One above the button and to the right of the dummy -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/dummy"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: cool, and how could I extend this to add another ListView to the right of the original 2 and have them each occupy a third of the screen, I tried adding another one in that is just toRightOf lv2 but It seems to be squashed in the corner


edit: Just trying to get a better understanding of the layouts in general also, rather than as exactly specific to the question

Comment: You asked for **2** ones. To set **3** equally spaced ones, you have to use a LinearLayout with weights. BUT. Because of the Button, you will need another layout. Which breaks the layout nesting avoidance.

Comment: Once again you were right, I did only want two so sorry for any confusion but like I mentioned in the comment above I was just wondering how I can extend the answers. Thanks for providing an alternative for the question which avoids layout nesting!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this way ....

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_gravity="right" android:layout_weight="0.1" android:gravity="right" android:orientation="horizontal" > <Button android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="New Button" /> </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This definitely works too, but why do we need to place an invisible button, seems like a bit of a strange method of getting right alignment

Comment: <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         
            android:text="New Button" />
    </LinearLayout>